# Tabular cells with exact same width and multicolumn

Tags: tables, tabularx, width, multicolumn

I tried to design a table with some very specific preferences:

- The table should span across the whole width
- Each cell can have a different alignment
- Each cell has exactly the same width
- Some cells are multicolumn cells, 2 combined cells should have exactly the same width as 2 single cells

Here is a small sample of what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=5mm, footskip=10mm, headheight=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|} \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{3 cells left}  & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1 cell right} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1 cell right}  & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{3 cells left} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1 cell right}  & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1 cell right} & \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{2 cells right} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1 cell right}  & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1 cell right} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1 cell right}   & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1 cell right} \\ \hline 
    \end{tabularx}         
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The first column in this example is significantly smaller than the others.
I really hope that somebody can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems stem from the fact that your  table, defined with 4 X columns really has none. It suffices to re-define X column type so as to ensure right alignment, and you'll have both a table that looks like what you want, and a simpler code. I also suppressed redundant vertical lines in \multicolumns:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=25mm, hmargin=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=5mm, footskip=10mm, headheight=25mm]{geometry}%

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{3 cells left} & 1 cell right \\
         \hline
        1 cell right & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{3 cells left} \\
        \hline
        1 cell right & 1 cell right & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{2 cells right} \\
        \hline
        1 cell right & 1 cell right & 1 cell right & 1 cell right \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\noindent` instruction just ahead of `\begin{table}` isn't needed.

Comment: Yes, it was in the O.P.'s code and I didn't notice it. Line removed

Answer (score 3):

Here is a try using `\hsize`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=5mm, footskip=10mm, headheight=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|} \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=3\hsize}X|}{3 cells left}  &
           \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft}X|}{1 cell
                  right} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedleft}X|}{1 cell right}  &
            \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=3\hsize}X|}{3 cells left} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedleft}X|}{1 cell right}  &
            \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft}X|}{1 cell right} &
%               \multicolumn{1}{X}{} &
                \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\raggedleft}X|}{2 cells
                 right} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedleft}X|}{1 cell right}  &
           \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft}X|}{1 cell right} &
             \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft}X|}{1 cell right}   &
               \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft}X|}{1 cell right} \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The 2 cells right column in your solution is actually a one cell column, I tried making it a 2 cell column with the \hzise solution but with \hsize=2\hsize the text is not aligned correct.

Comment: @Hemeroc When you use `\raggedleft` you have to add `2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth` in `2 cells right column` like `>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\raggedleft}X|`. Remember that redefining `tabularxcolumn` as in the other answer makes all `X` columns in other tables `\raggedleft`.  I have updated the answer.